# No launch bar appears

Tags: upgrade

After installing 800+ upgrades in ubuntu 12.04 and after restart there is no launch bar on the left side. The screen has only the background image. What to do? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

`sudo service lightdm restart`

If lightdm fails to get back to normal :-

then Run:-

```
`sudo apt-get update`

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no window where to enter The command it is only The background .gif file. How can I get The command window? Thanks again.

Comment: try running `ctrl+alt+F1`

Comment: @cristi you can press *Ctrl+Alt+T* to open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve this issue is generally to reset your Unity settings. This is easy to do, however keep in mind that it will reset the left bar as well, so **the icons you put there will not be remembered.** They will be rearranged as they were right after you installed Ubuntu.

Directions:

- Do not log in at the log-in screen
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a virtual console
- Log in there (you won't see the password while you are typing it)
- Carefully type:

  ```
  rm $HOME/.config/dconf/user
  ```

  (The only space is between `rm` and `$`)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to log out
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the log-in screeen
- Log in

This might not be the only solution, but it is a quick one to apply when the Dconf configuration gets corrupted.